# Why do some people have cold hands and some have warm?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, temperature

I've known people who have warm hands even in the most chilling weather and also those having cold hands in a relatively hot climate. Why does this happen?

Comment: Although there is certainly something to this phenomenon regarding circulation and other factors, I think it's important to note that this is very relative: the people with cold hands are people with *colder hands than you* and the people with warm hands are people with *warmer hands than you* in either circumstance.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Homoeopathy "medicine" is not in any way empirically more effective than a placebo. I used quotations because sugar pills are as effective, and sometimes more so than homoeopathic treatment. If hot hands are used as a diagnostic tool in homoeopathy, it doesn't mean that symptom has any biological or medical underpinning.

Comment: @James I won't argue, it being more effective or not as compared to placebo. I have been taking them since time unknown(before I could have any expectations). I often wonder how it works actually (I believe it does). Well, it was a comment, just trying to add an information which can be considered not constructive,the science behind it is unknown( with a bit of research I have done). Hence I delete.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh [A meta-study in 2002](https://goo.gl/o2v66S) found that there was no consistent evidence that homoeopathy is effective above placebo level. [The controversial](https://www.statnews.com/2016/06/17/homeopathy-journal-thomson-reuters/) journal of homeopathy remains in dispute. No article I know of outside this journal has found evidence in support of homoeopathy. As for understanding homoeopathy, it is extremely diluted medicine. There is no mechanism by which it works without [fundamentally misunderstanding physics](https://youtu.be/SAOy9PZd_tQ?t=29s).

Comment: @James I won't blame either you or @ SanjuktaGhosh for this...homoeopathy is still the first choice for many in (at least) India. And people (don't know why) don't like homoeopathy being called as pseudoscience... :/

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Probably because the only way that homeopathy has any chance of working (and the only way for homeopathy peddlers to get anyone to buy their goods) is via a placebo effect; the more people understand that it is pseudoscience, the less effective the placebo effect will be.

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't heard of people having warm hands in cold temperatures (unless your using a hot pack or something), there are biological explanations for cold hands.

> Having cold hands even when you're not in a cold environment is
>   common. Often, having cold hands is a part of your body's natural
>   response to regulate your body temperature and shouldn't be cause for
>   concern.
>
> But if you have persistently cold hands, particularly if accompanied
>   by color changes, it could be a warning sign. For example, having cold
>   hands could mean you have a problem with the nerves or blood
>   circulation or a problem with tissue damage in your hands or fingers.
>   If you are outside in extreme cold weather and you have cold hands,
>   you should watch for warning signs of frostbite.
>   - MayoClinic

Other than frostbite, there are also reports of the Reynaud's disease.

Sources:
[Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/cold-hands/basics/definition/sym-20050648)
[CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2016/02/22/health/reason-why-cold-hands/)

Comment: Hi, GH05T, and welcome. A mostly copy/paste text doesn't make for a high quality answer on SE sites. Paraphrases of relevant information with quotes as necessary, plus references are much more in keeping with the SE model. Just letting you know, not trying to offend. Thanks, and again, welcome.